# Sample statistics with 1 less data point

Tags: variance, mean, moments

If I define the sample mean as

$$\displaystyle {\it Mean}\, = \,{\frac {\sum _{i=1}^{n}x_{{i}}}{n}}$$

and then exclude one data point, say $y$, then the new average becomes as follows:

$$\displaystyle {\frac {{\it Mean}\,n-y}{n-1}}$$

How are the formulas for the sample variance and the sample central moment?

Comment: Is this a homework question?  If so, please include the self-study tag.  Also, what is the difference between $Mean$ here and $Meann$?  Is this just a typo?  Is  your population considered infinite or finite and your observations independent?  The answer to this will impact your variance computations.

Comment: The sample mean is based on sample size $n,$ sample sum $T= \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2/$.  The sample variance uses $n, T$ and $Q=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2:$ The formula is $(n-1)S^2 = Q-T^2/n.$ Somewhat messy algebra using this formula will allow you to do what you want. Perhaps begin by expressing $S^2$ for $n$ observations in terms of $S^2$ for $n-1$ observations and the additional observation.

Comment: To  StatsStudent. This is _not_ a  homework question, but a research question. $Mean$ $n$ simply means $Mean$ times $n$. I am talking about sampling statistics, _not_ about population statistics.